# Reference for the $3$-series of an elliptic formal group law

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves, formal-groups

The $3$-series of the formal group law of the Weierstrass curve $y^2 = x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_4 x$ begins
$$
[3](z) = 3 z - 8 a_2 z^3 + (24 a_2^2 - 96 a_4) z^5 - (72 a_2^3 - 288 a_2 a_4) z^7 + (216 a_2^4 - 1472 a_2^2 a_4 + 2432 a_4^2) z^9 + \dots
$$
(assuming I did not make a mistake).  Is there a published reference that contains this information, including the coefficient of $z^9$?

Comment: sage: R.<a2,a4> = QQ[]; E = EllipticCurve([0,a2,0,a4,0]); E.formal_group().mult_by_n(3)

Comment: In [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) it is $\texttt{E=ellinit([0,a2,0,a4,0]); m=9; subst(ellformalexp(E,m),x,3*ellformallog(E,m))}$.